# XML Layout files does not open at Android Studio on Mac

Tags: java, android, xml, macos, android-studio

I working on a Mac and in some reason, my XML Layout files does not open in Android Studio. I checked, and they are valid and declared as "XML" and not as "Plain Text" files by mistake.
It's throws me this exception (I couldn't find it):

```
ClassCastException: org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrClosableBlockImpl cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.api.statements.arguments.GrNamedArgument
```

**those are the details -**

```
org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrClosableBlockImpl cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.api.statements.arguments.GrNamedArgument
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrClosableBlockImpl cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.api.statements.arguments.GrNamedArgument
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.GradleDslParser.parse(GradleDslParser.java:265)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.GradleDslParser.access$100(GradleDslParser.java:107)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.GradleDslParser$1.visitApplicationStatement(GradleDslParser.java:200)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.GrApplicationStatementImpl.accept(GrApplicationStatementImpl.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementImpl.acceptGroovyChildren(GroovyPsiElementImpl.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.blocks.GrBlockImpl.acceptChildren(GrBlockImpl.java:82)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.GradleDslParser.parse(GradleDslParser.java:192)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.GradleDslParser.parse(GradleDslParser.java:186)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.GradleDslParser.parse(GradleDslParser.java:110)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModel$GradleBuildDslFile$1.process(GradleBuildModel.java:347)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModel$GradleBuildDslFile$1.visitMethodCallExpression(GradleBuildModel.java:333)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.statements.expressions.path.GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.accept(GrMethodCallExpressionImpl.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.GroovyPsiElementVisitor.visitElement(GroovyPsiElementVisitor.java:34)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementBase.accept(PsiElementBase.java:274)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.SharedImplUtil.acceptChildren(SharedImplUtil.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.acceptChildren(PsiFileImpl.java:845)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModel$GradleBuildDslFile.parse(GradleBuildModel.java:330)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.GradleDslFile.parse(GradleDslFile.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModel.parseBuildFile(GradleBuildModel.java:107)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.GradleBuildModel.get(GradleBuildModel.java:94)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dependencies.GradleDependencyManager.findMissingDependencies(GradleDependencyManager.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.DependencyManager.checkForNewMissingDependencies(DependencyManager.java:106)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.DependencyManager.setPalette(DependencyManager.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.NlPalettePanel.setToolContext(NlPalettePanel.java:159)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.NlPalettePanel.setToolContext(NlPalettePanel.java:51)
    at com.android.tools.adtui.workbench.AttachedToolWindow.updateContent(AttachedToolWindow.java:273)
    at com.android.tools.adtui.workbench.AttachedToolWindow.<init>(AttachedToolWindow.java:99)
    at com.android.tools.adtui.workbench.WorkBench.addToolsToModel(WorkBench.java:352)
    at com.android.tools.adtui.workbench.WorkBench.init(WorkBench.java:107)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlEditorPanel.<init>(NlEditorPanel.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlEditor.getComponent(NlEditor.java:53)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlEditor.getComponent(NlEditor.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite.createEditorComponent(EditorComposite.java:187)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite.createTabbedPaneWrapper(EditorComposite.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite.<init>(EditorComposite.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorWithProviderComposite.<init>(EditorWithProviderComposite.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.createComposite(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1020)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.lambda$openFileImpl4$6(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:890)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2453)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl4(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:971)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl3(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:788)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.lambda$openFileImpl2$4(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:770)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl2(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:770)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileWithProviders(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:711)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.ex.FileEditorManagerEx.openFile(FileEditorManagerEx.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.lambda$openEditor$9(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openEditor(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.OpenFileDescriptor.navigateInAnyFileEditor(OpenFileDescriptor.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.OpenFileDescriptor.navigateInEditor(OpenFileDescriptor.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.OpenFileDescriptor.navigateInEditorOrNativeApp(OpenFileDescriptor.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.OpenFileDescriptor.navigate(OpenFileDescriptor.java:115)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.navigate(PsiFileImpl.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.navigation.NavigationUtil.openFileWithPsiElement(NavigationUtil.java:176)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.navigate(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:235)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.navigate(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:245)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.PsiFileNode.navigate(PsiFileNode.java:133)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:53)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.openSourcesFrom(OpenSourceUtil.java:31)
    at com.intellij.util.EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler$TreeMouseListener.processDoubleClick(EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler.java:130)
    at com.intellij.util.EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler$TreeMouseListener.onDoubleClick(EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler.java:122)
    at com.intellij.ui.DoubleClickListener.onClick(DoubleClickListener.java:30)
    at com.intellij.ui.ClickListener$1.mouseReleased(ClickListener.java:73)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.processMouseEvent(Tree.java:443)
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.aware.DnDAwareTree.processMouseEvent(DnDAwareTree.java:59)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Disable Android support plugin and that should fix the problem for you.